# Original reference by Esseen for Berry-Esseen theorem

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem, large-deviation-theory

Does someone have an idea of where I can find an officially published text of the following seminal article by Esseen?

"Esseen, Carl-Gustav (1942). "On the Liapunoff limit of error in the theory of probability". Arkiv för Matematik, Astronomi och Fysik. A28: 1–19. ISSN 0365-4133"

I cannot find it. I can only find this short review by Feller.

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=11909

It would be astounding to me if there were no way to access such an important paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it through the library network of German universities. If you are part of a German university, you can ask your university library to send you a scanned copy through the university library network.

[https://katalog.ub.uni-freiburg.de/opac/Interlending/Search?type=allfields&lookfor=id:\(DE-627\)336768281](https://katalog.ub.uni-freiburg.de/opac/Interlending/Search?type=allfields&lookfor=id:%5C(DE-627%5C)336768281)

There seems to exist no online version as far as I can tell.